# Keyboard left arrow goes to next picture; right arrow to previous - Windows 10 Photo app

Tags: windows-10, photos

When I open a photo in the Photos app (Windows 10), and I use my keyboard's right arrow, this brings me to the previous picture in the folder... The same happens, by the way, when I use the left/right arrows next to the photos in the app. I cannot tell under which version it still was OK, and I'm sure it was this app, since I've been using it for at least a year (and probably a couple of years) now.

Anyone have the same experience? How to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure of the past behavior of this specific application, it would be very strange for the functionality of an application, to be so dramatically changed?  Are you sure you are not thinking of a different application?  What version of Windows 10 were you using when the functionality was different?  Edit your question with the necessary information to answer your question.